# Let T=(E,V) be a tree then for any nonempty subset $S\subset V$ of vertices the number of edges with both endpoints in S is less or equal to $|S|-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

So I wanted to proof the following:
Suppose we have a tree : T=(E,V), then for all nonempty subsets $S \subset V$ of vertices the number of edges with both endpoints in S is less or equal to $|S|-1$.

Proof:

Suppose we have a tree T=(E,V) and consider a nonempty subset $S\subset V$. We have 3 cases:

- If S=V, then the statement is trivial since T is a tree.
- If we take S such that all vertices in S are connected by some edge between then every pair of vertices is exactly connected by one edge. Since we are connected this means this actually a subtree of T and we have $|S|-1$ edges. If it was more than we would have a cycle in our tree T itself and that is not possible.
- If we take S randomly, by randomly I mean that the pairs should not be connected necessarily, then every pair in S which is connected has exactly 1 edge between them and the ones which are not connected will have no edges. Since every pair in S is not connected this is strictly less than $|S|-1$.

Is my proof correct? I think that the third case should be explained in a better way? Any tips or advice please

Comment: The wording "[...]such that all vertices in S are connected by some edge between
 them" is perhaps not what you want. Let $E_S$ be the set of edges with both endpoints in $S$. Then $(S,E_S)$ is a subgraph of $T$ which is again acyclic.
If $(S,E_S)$ is connected, then it is a tree (that is your second point).
If $(S,E_S)$ is not connected then it decomposes into connected components
$(S_1,E_{S_1}),\ldots (S_k,E_{S_k})$. By adding up the equations
$|E_{S_i}| = |S_i| - 1$ you will obtain $ |E_S| = |S| - k \leq |S| - 1$

Comment: @MarcOlschok Thanks man great advice